# How do I implement Coloris npm package as a custom element?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element, velo, coloris

I have been trying to implement an NPM called [Coloris](https://coloris.js.org/), to provide end-user color customization capability to a Wix website through a web component. From what I can see, the javascript isn't working/executing. I've tried a few solutions for getting javascript to work in innerHTML, but they haven't worked so far. This issue has stumped me for a week and I still can't get the Coloris color picker to show/render. I can get as an HTML/IFrame embed, but need to make it work as a custom component

Below is the code for the web component. Any help/solutions would be greatly appreaciated

```
const createScript = () => {

const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

scriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js";

scriptElement.defer = true;

scriptElement.async = true;

return scriptElement;

}

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-coloris>
`


class ColorisImp extends HTMLElement {
  
  connectedCallback() {

    this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.appendChild(createScript());
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
   
  
  }
  

  
}

window.customElements.define('coloris-implement', ColorisImp);
```

Comment: Why do you want a shadowDOM? Have you checked with the maker if usage in a shadowroot is supported?

Comment: I'm rather new to custom elements. I don't have a preference for using a shadowDOM, I've just been testing different solutions I've found on the web to see if they would work. Currently I'm just trying to get the color picker to show in a custom element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it, ColorIs does not work on DOM Elements **inside** shadowDOM

Your code can be made easier; to inject the `<script>` and `<link>` in the document.head

Note: ColorIs does not work properly in this SO snippet either;
here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/5j7h3ygw/

```html
<script>
  window.customElements.define('color-is', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      const source = "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/";
      if (!document.querySelector(`[src*="${source}"]`)) { // add script once
        const create = (tag, props) =>
          Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
        document.head.append(
          create('script', {
            src: source + "coloris.min.js",
            defer: true,
            async: true
          }),
          create('link', {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            href: source + "coloris.min.css"
          })
        ); //append
      }
      // create Coloris element
      this.innerHTML = `<input type="text" data-coloris>`;
    }
  });
</script>

<color-is></color-is>
```

Comment: I removed references to the shadowDOM and it displays now

Comment: Note that this adds a new script tag every time this component is used

Comment: Good observation. I added a check for script already loaded

Answer (score 0):

I changed up the code with the suggestion by Danny

```
const createScript = () => {

const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');

scriptElement.src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js";

scriptElement.defer = true;

scriptElement.async = true;

return scriptElement;

}

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-coloris>
`


class ColorisImp extends HTMLElement {
  
  connectedCallback() {


var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mdbassit/Coloris@latest/dist/coloris.min.js"></script>;`;
document.body.appendChild(script);
    //this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
    this.appendChild(createScript());
    this.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
   
  
  }
  

  
}

window.customElements.define('coloris-implement', ColorisImp);
```